# Can't list multiple usernames at once using YouTube API

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm new to python and I'm trying to make a bulk username to channel id converter since I couldn't find any online. However it seems to only allow one username at a time and whenever I try putting multiple it says : `{'totalResults': 0}`.

Here is the code I was trying to use:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

api_key = 'KEY'
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)
request = youtube.channels().list(
    part='id, snippet',
    forUsername=('jawed','mw'))
response = request.execute()

with open('output.txt', 'a', encoding="utf-8" ) as f:
    f.write(str(response) + '\n')
    print(response)
```

Comment: As far as I know you can only proceed usernames one by one.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#parameters), the `forUsername` parameter only allows you to specify a single username to list. You won't be able to search for multiple usernames in the same query.

If you know the IDs of the channels you wish to search for, the `id` parameter allows you to specify a comma-separated list of IDs to search for instead. This is the only way to get multiple channels in the same query if the channels aren't owned by the authenticated user (or aren't managed by the authenticated user, in the case of content partners like MCNs).